# Columns shows like rows in Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, multiple-columns

I want to create three columns like I do with Bootstrap 3, but here I don't get three columns and I get three rows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="popper.js@1.12.9" data-semver="1.12.9" src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class = "container-fluid">
      <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-md-4">Left</div>
        <div class = "col-md-4">Center</div>
        <div class = "col-md-4">Right</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/6gRm3dsYxBjCdKR5V7Dy?p=info

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit I

Here is the wide of my screen:

[image]

As you can see I don't get columns, I get rows. The width of my screen is bigger than 1200px.

I'm using Angular 5.

### Fixed

It was my fault. I didn't include Bootstrap CSS file in my angular code.

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you getting rows at a specific screen width?

Comment: That image looks nothing like your plnkr

Comment: I have checked in plunker works fine, but the same code with Angular 5, doesn't work to me :(

Comment: You need to **show the code that reproduces the problem**. The code you've showed does not.

Answer (score 0):

You do get three columns in fact, but only for screens of size `md` and greater. Resize the output (make it larger) to see the columns.

To get three columns on screens smaller than `md` you need to tell bootstrap that you want 3 columns on smaller screens. In bootstrap v4, thats:

```
    <div class = "col-4">Left</div>
    <div class = "col-4">Center</div>
    <div class = "col-4">Right</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, if your screen width is anything less than 768px, the columns will automatically stack on top of each other instead of the way you intend.